# Can Any one help me in finding the correct format for this

Tags: asp.net, eval

Here is My Code for the button

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%# (Eval("ReviewAttachment").ToString().Trim().Substring(Eval("ReviewAttachment").ToString().Trim().LastIndexOf('\\') + 1)) %>' ID="lnkRefDoc" CssClass="btn-link"></asp:LinkButton>
```

It's giving me this error

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: because it show the whole path of the file while i only want to show the name of the file

Comment: what is the pattern for `ReviewAttachment` , how it looks like?

Comment: its just complete path for the file stored in data base

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" 
                                     Text='<%# System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Eval("ReviewAttachment").ToString())%>' 
                                     ID="lnkRefDoc" CssClass="btn-link"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: its done with the same code by just changing LastIndexOf('\\') to LastIndexOf("\\"). thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

Use double-quotes for `LastIndexOf`

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" 
    Text='<%# Eval("ReviewAttachment").ToString().Trim().Substring(Eval("ReviewAttachment").ToString().Trim().LastIndexOf("\\") + 1) ) %>'  ID="lnkRefDoc" CssClass="btn-link" />
```

Or use code-behind which can be handy. Thanks